# Evernote to store questions?

Tags: feature-request

I use Evernote a lot for clipping items for reference or later retrieval. The best part is that the clipper stores the URL of where I found the information so I could go back and look at the original source. I have had the problem with the Firefox and Safari extensions.

I found out today that it doesn't work at all with the StackOverflow site. I figured I better report it as a possible bug (maybe it's a feature?).

Comment: Are you using the firefox plugin or what?  Perhaps you could include more details about how replicate this *bug* that you are trying to report so someone else could try and replicate it?

Comment: This is the web clipper extensions that cause problems. Clip the whole page or a portion thereof with multiple answers and neither works.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used *evernote*, but the fact that it doesn't work properly with Stack Overflow doesn't mean Stack Overflow is buggy :) Every post on Stack Overflow has a unique url by which you can refer back to any question/answer.

The only problem(s) I could see is if you store a reference to an item that is later deleted. That would cause a bit of confusion.

Comment: It tells me that it doesn't work with this site. I could store just the URL, but that doesn't help in searching later. Maybe, I should have thought this through more and reported it to Evernote?

Comment: @Mike The url (for questions) contains the question title, which is searchable. You'll need to be more specific about *why* it doesn't work with Evernote. Any specific suggestions that might make the two work together?

Comment: While `SO > evernote`, it is true.  After `evernote` becomes `> SO`, it turns false with dramatic speed.

Comment: I disagree, @Pavel. *Evernote* could be hugely popular and still be the problem. Think of things like Internet Explorer, Outlook 2007, etc. Just because your product doesn't work properly in a popular environment doesn't mean your product is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote now has a [site memory button](http://blog.evernote.com/2010/09/24/site-memory-button-wordpress-plugin/). This would be a cool integration into StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with Evernote on Mac and the Safari clipper plugin. Clipping the whole page or part of a page works. Maybe this was a temporary Evernote bug that now has been fixed?

Comment: Oh wait, I crossed my streams here. Sorry.